# CMake on Ubuntu: Could NOT find Threads (missing: Threads_FOUND)

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-20.04, emsdk, onx

I'm trying to compile Onx and I am receiving a CMake error message.

I am receiving this error on my ubuntu 20.04 lts:

**Could NOT find Threads (missing: Threads_FOUND)**

I'm waiting your comments. Thanks for help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMake on Mac: Could NOT find Threads (missing: Threads\_FOUND)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54587052/cmake-on-mac-could-not-find-threads-missing-threads-found)

Comment: Onx seems to be old and doesn't seem to know that modern c runtimes have built in thread support. Remove `if` condition from the answer in the duplicated question, or replace with `if(UNIX)`.

Answer (score 2):

When CMake runs it tests for the presence of a number of required libraries and features by compiling test programs. Because the thread library is one of the first things it searches for, any problem with the toolchain may cause the test compilation to fail and show this error.

Look in the `CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log` file to determine why the compilation is failing and take steps to fix the errors. It may or may not have anything to do with the threads library itself.

Comment: Another place to look it `CMakeFiles/CMakeConfigureLog.yaml`